# Python: How to do recursion in Python using nested min and max functions?

Tags: python, recursion, networkx

This question is an extension of my [query](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3193812/recursive-formula-for-the-definition-of-tree-depth-of-a-graph) that I posted on math.stackoverflow. Now that I understand the working of the algorithm, I am trying to implement it in Python.

I am using [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) for the graph representation. I tried to shorten algorithm by combining the second and third case limb together under the assumption that the imput graph is connected.

I plan to use to use the `min` and `max` to retrieve the minimum of the maximum tree-depth of each component. This is the code I have:

```py
def td(G):                                  # G is an input connected graph
    G_copy = G.copy()
    nodesList = list(G.nodes)

    if (len(G_copy.nodes) == 1):
        depth = 1                           # Base case for the recursion
    else:
#        G_copy.remove_node(next(iter(nodesList), None))
#        depth = 1 + min(max([iter], key), key)  # Recursive step

    return depth
```

My questions are:

1. Can the `min` and `max` be nested in the aforementioned way to shorten the algorithm?
2. Either way, how can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, you pass your minimum and maximum value as parameter into your recursive function as below:

```
my_array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, [3, 4, 5, 6, [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]]


def get_min_max(my_list, min_val=False, max_val=False):
    for num in my_list:
        if isinstance(num, list):
            min_val, max_val = get_min_max(num, min_val, max_val)
        else:
            if min_val is False or num < min_val:
                min_val = num
            if max_val is False or num > max_val:
                max_val = num
    return min_val, max_val


min_num, max_num = get_min_max(my_array)

print(min_num, max_num)
```

Output

```
0 9
```

Comment: :: Hi @acb16ua if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested this is the working implementation of the algorithm. It does not have the nested `min` and `max` but it works and also takes a long time because of O(2^n) complexity.

```py
def td(G):

    copG = G.copy()
    depth = 0

    if (len(copG.nodes) == 1):
        depth = 1

    elif (len(copG.nodes) > 1 and nx.is_connected(copG)):
        someList = []

        for v in list(copG.nodes)[:-1]:
            edges = list(copG.edges(v))
            copG.remove_node(v)            
            someList.append(td(copG))
            copG.add_node(v)
            copG.add_edges_from(edges)

        depth = 1 + min(someList)

    elif(len(copG.nodes) > 1 and not nx.is_connected(copG)):
        someList2 = []
        for i in (copG.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(copG)):
            someList2.append(td(i))

        depth = max(someList2)


    return depth
```